How to solve Contentlayer schema problem on window system
I have a contentlayer.config.ts file that I'm using for my website, based on NextJS. I've been working on the project on Linux and Windows, deployed to Vercel from Linux initially. I've went back to modifying my project from Windows and encountered a weird error when trying to run build.
The error (appearing in .contentlayer.config.ts file)

error: Error: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. On Windows, absolute paths must be valid file:// URLs. Received protocol 'c:'

I've tried modifying the absolute paths to relative ones in the pages I have created before the error appeared. Tried checking for any import mistyping or similar issues. Looked on the forums, updated node and contentlayer, didn't work.

They're not referring to the file system directly, the file:// url is how browser's address local files. You should be able to just add the file:// url pattern followed by the file system path. If you don't want to set the path to be absolute however, you'll need to make it absolute using something like const absolutePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "myPath/..."), which combined would give something like const thePath = 'file://${absolutePath}'

Good point but unfortunately this doesn't work. It seems to be a common bug with node currently, while using Next.
I've seen to workarounds around this problem for now, one which changes the
export default config;
to
module.exports = config;
Another one would be to use newUrl for the absolute paths but that didn't do it for me. I've managed to make progress by changing the names files from CommonJS to Ecma but now I'm having another error with another file, not finding the import.
